# Data formatting in rails using scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models User, Order, OrderItem

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
end 

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

OrderItem contains a field **amount**, i need to get total amount of an order for a particular user in the format

```
{{1=>23.5},{2=>213.5},{5=>123.5}}
```

where 1,2,3 are the order id and the corresponding value is the sum of all amount in the order item of a particular order.

I need this kind of data for displaying a chart using [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) gem

where the data must be in any one of the form,

```
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
<%= pie_chart [["Football", 10], ["Basketball", 5]] %>
```

please refer https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#data

So i need to get this kind of data.

I have achieved it by

```
  result = User.first.orders.select("orders.id, sum(order_items.amount) as charge").left_outer_joins(:order_items)
```

where the result is `[{"id"=>206, "charge"=>240000.0}, {"id"=>208, "charge"=>0.0}, {"id"=>210, "charge"=>120000.0}]`

But this can be converted to format that i have mentioned by using a loop, but i don't want this kind of solution, and i need to know is there any other straight forward approach.

Comment: Try with this -> Order.joins(:order_items).group(:order_id).sum("order_items.amount")

Comment: `user.orders.joins(:order_items).group('orders.id').sum('order_items.amount')` should work

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid ruby so you may want to clarify exactly what you're expecting/desiring as output. It looks like you want an array of hashes - but in actual fact if you've got unique order ids then you only need a single hash. It also looks like you want strings whereas your comment suggests these values are stored as numbers.

Comment: Standard advice: don't use floats for currency.

Comment: Here 1,2 and 5 are order id. And 89, 206,208 are? @BalaKarthik

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary sorry its a copy pate error. i just got an output as {89=>0.0, 206=>120000.0, 208=>120000.0, 210=>120000.0} but i need something as {{89=>0.0}, {206=>120000.0}, {208=>120000.0}, {210=>120000.0}}

Comment: @mudasobwa i just wanted question to be straight forward thats why I didn't explain it elaborately, now I have made changes in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Changes inside you application:

> 1. Order Model

```
        def to_array
          [self.id, self.order_items.sum(:amount)]
        end
```

> 2.Use Below Query for get result:

```
        current_user.orders.includes(:order_items).map(&:to_array) ##for single user order
                         ##OR##
        Order.all.map(&:to_array)  ##for all order
```

> 3. This will Give Result like Below ex:

```
        [[1, "100"]] ## id of your order and total sum of amount.
```

hope it will work fine:)

Comment: I think that you have misunderstood the problem. I need the order_id and the sum of order items amount.